# Comparing Database Searching Methods

Tags: c++, search

I am writing in a c++ class, a program that searches a database. I wrote code that reads one record (line) from the .txt file that is the database. I stored the values for the record in a vector and compared the content of the corresponding column (element in vector) to the search query. When I got to class the teacher said to make index files for the columns that will be searched and compare the query to one of the sub-files. I am of course going to rework my code to fit the teachers parameters. I'm still wondering what the difference is between the two, and if one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really believe, that the teacher's approach is better. Every file access costs, and it costs much. A real improvement will be minimizing file accesses count. You waste a lot of time, when you read file line by line. You should create some buffer, f.e. 64kB. This will increase performance significantly.

To be specific: when I was working with files long time ago, I used naive approach to read data from it like from standard input:

```
std::cin >> someData;
// Similarly
file >> someData;
```

**Nope**.
If you respect your time, don't do like this.
In perspective: 5 MB file using naive approach took me about 1-2 minutes to load. Then I've significantly reduced number of accesses and it took 5 seconds to load. This is just an example, but you can realize how big step it is.

Comment: I'd say half of truth only. Why do all major database systems use indices/allow to create them? They can speed up finding data sets, compare `std::vector` (`O(n)`) vs. `std::unordered_map` (`O(1)`; in theory at least). But it's a heavy task finding a good balance between minimized file access and still profiting best as possible from these indices...